# How can I dynamically offset the position of a child element to 50% of it's own size?

Tags: html, css

Exactly as the title says, I have an element that dynamically resizes itself to fit the content. I would like this element to be positioned proportionally to its size (so it stays centered on a fixed point). The problem I'm facing is that the parent element I'm using to position the child element is not inheriting the calculated size of the child element. I don't know if there's any CSS tricks to make the parent element get it's child's height without having to specify it using javascript.

The following fiddle demonstrates the problem, with the issue being displayed on the left and the desired final product on the right (minus the ability to do it dynamically).

http://jsfiddle.net/YEcx6/

The html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">This content is dynamic</div>
</div>
<div id="static" class="parent">
    <div class="child">This content is static</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.child {
 position: relative;    
 right: -50%;
 top: -50%;
}

.parent {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: 10px;
 background: #ddd;
}

#static {
 left: 100px;
 height: 54px;  
}

.child {
 background: red;
 max-width: 50px;
}
```

== EDIT ==

I now know there is no way to do any relational positioning with regard to height without using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

What about height:auto and width:auto on the parent ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in order to get the vertical positioning to work right, you need to have a defined height to reference by. Since you want a dynamic height, it makes it challenging. I tried using negative `margin-top` instead of `top` but that, as I suspected, defaults to using the `width` of the element to determine the `height` offset (which does not achieve your effect). I found a solution that *might* work for you if you can compromise by setting the position of the upper left corner of the `.child` rather than the upper left corner of the `.parent`. Here is the solution, with the explanation following (this was only tested in FF).

HTML

```
<div class="parent">  
    <div class="child">This content is dynamic
        <div class="bkg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50px;
   left: 10px;
}

.child {
   position: relative;    
}

.bkg{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 50%;
   bottom: -50%
   left: -50%;
   right: 50%;
   background-color: #ddd;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

The `.parent` now is supposed to be the final position of the upper left of where `.child` will be. The `.child` contains the content you want but gives a `relative` position by which `.bkg` will be related. By giving `.bkg` a `width` and `height` of 100%, that set's its size, which apparent is enough to correctly then calculate the correct 50% offsets to reposition it down and to the left (which is the same relationship you wanted for your original look).